# mysql opposite query of a join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. 2nd tables 2 PK referenced as 2FK from 1st table which are also 2 PK. i want to pull out the records that do not match?

The following query matches the records that match base on these 2 keys. This returns 3828 rows. how do i do the opposite>

```
SELECT * 
FROM hdb.addressesconsultants a
join orderconsultants o where a.CONSULTANT = o.CONSULTANT and a.ORDERNO = o.ORDERNO
```

below returns 3837 rows.

```
SELECT *  FROM hdb.addressesconsultants a
```

@munguea05

this did what i was after, it returned 9 rows which was the discrepancy, however i have 4044 rows in `orderconsultants` how do i resolve that or grab the rows that do not match to `addressconsultants` from `orderconsutlants`?

How can I delete these rows?

```
SELECT o.*
FROM hdb.orderconsultants o
LEFT OUTER JOIN addressesconsultants a 
ON a.CONSULTANT = o.CONSULTANT AND a.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
WHERE a.CONSULTANT is NULL and a.OrderNo is NULL
```

Comment: If you want to delete the rows just change the SELECT to a DELETE with the alias of the left table to delete the rows out of the left table that do not match the records in the right table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you want results from just one table that don't match, or results from both tables that don't match.

This gives you one, if you need the results from both just do the opposite.

```
SELECT *
FROM hdb.addressesconsultants a (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderconsultants o (NOLOCK)
ON A.consultant = o.Consultant AND a.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
WHERE o.Consultant is NULL and O.OrderNo is NULL
```

Comment: switch the hdb.addressesconsultants and orderconsultants so that the orderconsultants is first, which makes it the left part of the join and switch the alias for consultant and orderno from o. to a. Left join will give you everything you want from the left table (First table in the query). asking where the join condition is null for the right table (second query) will give you the results from the left table that aren't in the right table.

Answer (score 2):

You want those without an order?
Use a left join and consider only those that have NULL on the left joined table

```
SELECT * 
FROM hdb.addressesconsultants a
LEFT JOIN orderconsultants o 
ON a.CONSULTANT = o.CONSULTANT and a.ORDERNO = o.ORDERNO
WHERE
    o.CONSULTANT IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM hdb.addressesconsultants a
left join orderconsultants o where a.CONSULTANT = o.CONSULTANT and a.ORDERNO = o.ORDERNO
where o.CONSULTANT is null
```

This will show any entry for which there was an entry in addressesconsultants, but no corresponding entry in orderconsultants.